# reactjs passing form input values to a modal component

Tags: reactjs, state, render

I am preparing a reservation page which includes a form section, i prepared the form using react hook form and managed to render the input values after the user clicks the submit button in the reservation page (same page) using map, but now i want to pass these input values from the reservation page component to another component (modal component) in order to show it to the user after clicking submit to confirm his data.

i am new so i searched online and couldn't find a solution, i saw tutorials about lifting state up but it didn't help.
the point is that i will pass the values to the modal component then render the modal component in the reservation page again which is something i didn't do before at all.
below is the code for the email only to ease it up for you. thanks

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./ReservationFormStyles.css";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { DevTool } from "@hookform/devtools";
import { ErrorMessage } from "@hookform/error-message";
import FormModal from "./FormModal";

const ReservationForm = (props) => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const {
    register,
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isValid },
  } = useForm({ mode: "onChange" });
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log("Form Submitted", data);
    setList((ls) => [data]);
  };
  return (
    <main className="form-container">
      <h2>{props.title}</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div className="form-element">
          <label htmlFor="email">E-Mail *</label>
          <input
            id="email"
            {...register("email", {
              required: { value: true, message: "please enter your email" },
              pattern: {
                value: /\S+@\S+\.\S+/,
                message: "Entered value does not match email format",
              },
            })}
            type="email"
          ></input>
          <ErrorMessage
            errors={errors}
            name="email"
            render={({ message }) => <p>{message}</p>}
          />
     </form>
      <DevTool control={control} />
**      {list.map((a) => (
        <div>
          <li>{a.email}</li>
        </div>**
      ))}
      <FormModal />
    </main>
```